# I thought I had the 5 missing required positional requirements in there? Any thoughts please?

Tags: python, streamlit

```
import streamlit as st
import pickle

st.title('My first app')

model = open('model2.pkl','rb')
car_nb = pickle.load(model)  

def predict_price(name,year,nr_of_accidents,color_exterior,color_interior,car_mileage):
    
    prediction=car_nb.predict([['name','year','nr_of_accidents','color_exterior','color_interior','car_mileage']])
    print(prediction)
    return prediction

def main():
    
    st.title("Used Car Prices!!") 

    st.write('''
             # 
             ''')

    name = st.text_input("Car","Type Here")
    year = st.text_input("Year","Type Here")
    nr_of_accidents = st.text_input("Accidents","Type Here")
    color_exterior = st.text_input("Exterior Color","Type Here")
    color_interior = st.text_input('Interior Color', 'Type Here')
    car_mileage = st.text_input('Miles', 'Type Here')
    result=""
    
    if st.button("Predict"):
        result=predict_price(([['name','year','nr_of_accidents','color_exterior','color_interior','car_mileage']]))
    st.success('The price is {}'.format(result))

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

TypeError: predict_price() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'year', 'nr_of_accidents', 'color_exterior', 'color_interior', and 'car_mileage'

Comment: Why vote it down?

Comment: `predict_price` takes 5 arguments, but you're passing in a single list of strings. What's your intent there?

Comment: Like Carcigenicate said. You are passing in a list of a list. So it it's only one argument.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently copy-pasted invocation of `predict_price()` at the end of your code from line where you call `np.predict()`. This will not work as `predict_price()` expects 6 arguments as error message says and you are just passed one (nested list). You (most likely) should replace:

```
result=predict_price(([['name','year','nr_of_accidents','color_exterior','color_interior','car_mileage']]))
```

with

```
result = predict_price(name,year,nr_of_accidents,color_exterior,color_interior,car_mileage)
```

Comment: UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32') the preceding error is what yielded after changes. Any ideas, Marcin? Thanks

Comment: That's appears to be different question. If former one is solved by my answer, mark it accepted and then post another question - this is how Stackoverflow works